# SSAS Effective Rate Calculated Measure with dimension attribute

Tags: attributes, ssas, mdx, measure

I am trying to create an effective rate calculation in my cube, but can't seem to get it right. The calculation is:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Effective Rate]
AS
[measures].[commission]
/[measures].[units]
/[transaction].[days_in_period].currentmember
*[transaction].[days_in_year].currentmember*10000/10
```

The above calculation does not work at all; however, I have tried a number of variations without luck.

The problem is that both `[transaction].[days_in_period]` and `[transaction].[days_in_year]` are attributes in the transaction dimension and I can't seem to figure out how to define the calculation so it functions at the lowest grain and aggregates at higher levels.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure these are of type member i.e. not numeric type, so cannot be used in calculations.

```
[transaction].[days_in_period].currentmember
[transaction].[days_in_year].currentmember
```

You can pull out there values using the function `MemberValue`:

```
Member_Expression.MemberValue
```

So they become:

```
[transaction].[days_in_period].MemberValue
[transaction].[days_in_year].MemberValue
```

For readability you could add some braces to your calculation - currently a bit tricky knowing the order of the operations.